# Moving working jQuery autocomplete code into a central file breaks the code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been working on and testing the jQuery autcomplete functionality here on my test page where it is working: http://www.problemio.com/test.php (just type "ho" to see it work).

When I got it to work, I copied the code to a central JS file that I import.  Then it stopped working and you can see that it stopped working here on the 3rd form field: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php

Here is the code that I copied:

```
function log( message ) 
{
    $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}

$( "#category_field" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/problems/get_categories_ajax.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) 
    {
            log( ui.item ?
                ui.item.value :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});

$('#add_category').click(function() 
{
        alert ("in add category");
        // Now have to get value of the text entry area
        var category = $("#category_field").val(); // Works

        var text_area = $("#log").val();        
        alert ("text_area: " + text_area);

        // Should append to value of textarea what is in the category
        if ( text_area )
        {
            alert ("text area NOT EMPTY: " + text_area + " and category: " + category );
            text_area = text_area + " , " + category;    
        }
        else
        {
            //alert ("text area EMPTY: " + text_area + " and category: " + category );
            text_area = category;           
        }    

        // Now replace old text_area with new one
        $("#log").val(text_area); 

        // Now reset the text field
        $("#category_field").val("");
});

$('#category_form').bind('submit',function()
{
        // Get the variables
        var problem_id = 1;
        //var categories = $("#log").text();    
        var categories = $("#log").val();

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&categories=' + categories;
        alert ("Data string: " + dataString);

        // Now check if the problem_id or solution are empty
        if( !categories )
        {
            $('#categories_success').fadeIn(200).hide();
            $('#categories_error').fadeOut(200).show();         
        }   
        else
        {
            // Now check if the user is logged in
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/auth/check_login.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        // If we are logged in, now can make a call to add the categories
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/problems/add_categories_ajax.php",
                            data: dataString ,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                $('#categories_success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                $('#categories_error').fadeOut(200).hide();     

                                $("#log").val("");
                            },
                            error: function(data)
                            {
                                alert ("error");
                                //if ( data.status == 200 )
                                //{
                                //       $('.add_message_success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                //       $('.add_message_error').fadeOut(200).hide();   

                                //       $('#comments').html(data);                     
                            //  }
                                //alert ("could not add attempted solution to the database");
                            }
                        });                     

                    } ,
                    error: function(data)   
                    {
                        // Error case for checking if user is not logged in
                        $("#loginpopup").dialog();

                        return false;
                    }   // End of error
            }); // End of the first AJAX call.                  
        }  // End of else in this AJAX jQuery call.     

        return false;
    });
```

Any idea why the code broke when I copied it over?  The JavaScript console shows an error with some css file from the TinyMCE library that it can't find, but other than that, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the missing CSS file seems to be throwing an error when loading the JS. TinyMCE probably needs this file to function so it maybe throwing the error. Since the error isn't handled, the rest of your JS is not executed so your Autocomplete is never hooked in.

You can confirm this by running your autocomplete code manually in console of the browser

```
$( "#category_field" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/problems/get_categories_ajax.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) 
    {alert ("1");
            log( ui.item ?
                ui.item.value :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

Running the above in the console activated the autocomplete.

You can fix the error by making sure the CSS file is present, or by surrounding the error call with a try/catch and recovering.

Comment: thanks.  Can I surround the library import call with a try/catch block?  Is that typical?  Also, in the test page, the error message regarding the css is not there, and if I swap the code from there to the problemio.js file, that breaks that page too, even though there is no TinyMCE libraries there.

Comment: Hmmm, I just assumed it was TinyMCE throwing the error because you mentioned it. Looks like this might not be the case. Have you tried wrapping your jquery UI calls in a document.ready()?

Comment: not really.  I am new to jQuery so I wasn't sure how to replicate the document.ready in that library file I am putting the code into.  Originally, I did have the code in the document.ready wrapper.

Comment: Make sure all your jquery UI and any event binding calls are wrapped in document.ready(). Either that or move your script to the bottom of the page to make sure that the page loads before the scripts are activated.

Comment: how do I wrap those calls with the document.ready() when they are functions in that outside library problemio.js  - My understanding is that you can only wrap things in document.ready on page level, no?

Comment: Cool! JS functions can be passed as parameters. This means you can wrap anything in with document.ready. It's just a callback for the ready event.